# Usage of "we" as plural second-person

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I often hear people saying phrases of the type "How are *we* doing over here?" by servers at  restaurants, for example.  Obviously they mean "How are *you* (plural) doing?"  Where does this type of usage of "we" come from?  Is this pronoun misuse a regional thing?  Has it entered mainstream American English?  Am I wrong in thinking that it is incorrect?

Comment: I invariably respond to the overly cutesy and patronizingly familiar question "How are we today?" with "Not bad. And how are we?"

Comment: Where did I see somebody call this the "nurse *we*"?

Comment: @Robusto: I may steal that.

Comment: N.B. The phenomenon occurs in other languages-- I don't see a reason to assume it's restricted to a specific dialect of English.

Comment: Indeed, it also happens in Spanish

Comment: This is common in Australia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We

> **The patronizing "we"**
>
> The patronizing we is used sometimes
> in place of "you" to address a second
> party, hinting a facetious assurance
> that the one asked is not alone in his
> situation, that "I am with you, we are
> in this together". A doctor may ask a
> patient: And how are we feeling today?
> This usage is emotionally non-neutral
> and usually bears a condescending,
> ironic, praising, or some other
> flavor, depending on intonation:
> "Aren't we looking cute?"

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it's the "patronizing we" as mentioned in that article, though I doubt that every time it's used, it's meant in a patronizing tone (though I admit it comes across that way).

Comment: I agree. Added clarification

Comment: Ok. Noted. Still weird to get voted down at el&u

Answer (score 2):

This use of "we" that actually excludes  the "I" can also refer to a third party and exclude the "you." It is often empathetic and participatory in this case as well.

You're in the vet's waiting room with your cat and you say to the dog owner seated next to you. **"We're having our nails trimmed today."** The "we" does not include *you,* the dog owner, and the cat owner is not being patronizing (and is definitely not having a manicure).

The same holds for a mom and her son at the barber shop who says: **"We're getting our first grown-up haircut today."**

For me it's a type of "exclusive *we*" — perhaps an  "empathetic *we*," even if the surface empathy can be insincere, ironic, facetious, or patronizing. It's harder to make a "patronizing *we*" cover usages that are clearly well-intentioned, sympathetic, or intended to calm someone.

This Wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We) does not mention a "patronizing *we*" or a "dictatorial *we*," but rather a "second-person we" (*And how are we feeling today?*). However, we'd then have to add a "third-person *we*" as well to cover my examples. A term for the phenomenon should IMO reflect what's being done grammatically (the first person is excluded and either a "you" is being addressed or a third party (present or not) is being referred to) rather than they way it's  used (tone of voice, choice of words, implication, intent, etc.).

I do not see this usage of *we* in the OED, but only

> **Used confidentially or humorously to mean the person or persons
> addressed**, with whose interests the speaker thus identifies himself or
> herself (esp. by a doctor in friendly or cheering address to a
> patient); also used mockingly or reproachfully by a parent, intimate
> friend, etc.
>
> *Well, Jane, and how are we this morning?*

This does not cover the above examples of the cat owner talking to the dog owner or the mother with her son talking to the barber. Neither *we* means the person addressed.

(See also "[The Opposite of the Royal *We*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321447/the-opposite-of-the-royal-we)")

Comment: A good (and in the spirit of ELU, valid) measured broadening of the question. I expect that OED has a sense for 'patronising' that means 'avuncular', with little implication of condesension, but this would be swamped by the usual sense. There is an acceptable way of talking about/with young children (and dogs) that becomes demeaning as in the case of children they mature. 'Kiddyspeak _we_' doesn't sound good. // There's also the fact that using 'we' for 'you' can sound more friendly, less abrupt/distancing, if used carefully.