# Do you use both my home and our home to your friends?

Tags: vocabulary

> I want to hear about your first week. Send **us** an answer back with
>   Hedwig [Harry's owl].
>  (A note from Hagrid to Harry, Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)
>
> [Oxford](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/us)(British English, informal) **me** : Give us the newspaper,
>   will you?

Hagrid uses ‘us’ instead of ‘me,’ and the dictionary says it’s not only Hagrid’s expression. Then when you say to your friend that ‘would you like to come my home?’, do you also say ‘would you like to come our home?’? (In Korean, I can say even 'our mother' to my friend, indicating mine. Is it also proper in English?)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/usage-of-we-as-plural-second-person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard Americans use, what is known as the '[Majestic Pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majestic_plural)'; this "royal *we/us*" form in speech, but I never use it. Is this 'proper' usage? Sure. Such stuff is just a matter of personal preference in spoken and informal written English. I suppose it fits some folks' definition of being modest by not emphasizing themselves by saying "Send **us** a letter" instead of "Send **me** a letter", "Give **us** a call" instead of "Give **me** a call", etc.

The expression **our mother**, however, is another issue. This usage is only, really used by the king or queen. Most Americans wouldn't use this expression unless referring to the common mother of the speaker and listener or the common mother of a group (2 or more) siblings. Using the royal *we/our* here can sound pretentious for anyone but the king and queen.

The same goes for **our home**. I don't say **home** when I mean **house** or **apartment** (but that's another dispute), and I don't say **our {house / apartment / place}** unless I'm talking about where my family (wife & son) and I live. When I lived alone, I always said **My {house / apartment / place}**.

Comment: I can't get past your first sentence: "*I've heard Americans use this "royal we/us" form in speech, but I never use it.*". They use it, but they don't? The rest of this feels more like opinion than fact....

Comment: @Pureferret: See that 2nd pronoun: "I"? Some Yanks use it, but Bill Franke doesn't. Usage answers are all about opinion. Don't be fooled by "descriptive linguistics", which means only that the linguist or "usage expert" _describes as objectively **as possible** what people actually write & say_ **before prescribing** what someone should say or write. Do **you** know why people use the royal _we_? Where are **your facts**? Personal experience is a legit basis for some answers: I'm 70, not 17. I've added supportive "[facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majestic_plural)" to my answer.

Comment: My Apologies. For some reason I parsed out the *I* in my quote, and  I read it as: "*I've heard Americans use this "royal we/us" form in speech, but never use it.*", thus my confusion. When I questioned the rest of your answer I meant the way it comes across; compare these two: "*Only the king or queen gets to say this naturally*" vs "*This usage is only to be used by the king or queen, in most circumstances.*". Ultimately I respect your opinion on this, and thank you for adding that citation.

Comment: @Pureferret: You're welcome. And thank you for the challenge. I don't mind being challenged. Sometimes I'm wrong. I'm happy that I found that particular citation. I should've done that the first time.

Answer (score 5):

Just a note to document Bill Franke's answer, which reflects my own experience of US usage:

[*OED*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/466/mode/2up) notes this use of *us* for *me* as "*dial.* and *coll.*" (ie, dialectal and colloquial). It offers an 1828 citation, but it's certainly older than that; the last verse of Robert Burns' *Auld Lang Synte* (1796) starts

> And there’s a hand, my trusty fiere!
>   and **gie's** [ie, *give us*] a hand o’ thine!

But *OED* does not cite corresponding uses of *we* and *our*, only the "royal and imperial" and authorial or editorial uses.

Answer (score 5):

No, this particular colloquial use of *us* for *me* is restricted to the word *us* as an unstressed pronoun after the verb; *we* or *our* cannot be used in this sense.

In fact, all the examples I can think of have it as the *indirect object* of an imperative sentence: *Give us a bit!*, *Show us your new car*, *Send us a note*, or the syntactically similar *benefactive*: *Cut us another slice!.*

I don't think people use the construction with a direct object, as **Follow us* or **Watch us*.

Comment: As Wikipedia points out (now linked in my answer), Margaret Thatcher was criticized for using the royal _we_. She said: "['We have become a grandmother' was UK Prime Minister Margaret Thatcher's statement to the press in 1989, on the birth of her first grandchild, Mark Thatcher's son Michael.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/401700.html)". Most unnatural except for the Queen, I'm sure you'll agree. Who knows (or cares) what Maggie said in private?

Comment: The 'royal we' is _utterly_ different from this construction.

Comment: How is it _utterly_ different? That's a **strong but unsupported claim** that contradicts both UK and US sources. Why should I credit your claim? We are not amused. (8-O

Comment: Which sources does it contradict? StoneyB's reference to the OED specifically distinguishes it from the "royal and imperial" usage, which does include _we_ and _our_ as well as _us_. Hagrid uses _us_ in this way, but I don't think you'll find him using _we_ in the royal way. And as I pointed out, I'm pretty sure this _us_ has even further restricted distribution.

Comment: Your statement implies that Maggie's usage was not the royal we. I'm sorry, but when she or other politicians use _we_ that way, it's the royal we. There's no difference 'twixt a close-range rubber bullet in the eye & a lead slug in the eye, or an ice pick & a ballpoint pen, for that matter. They all blind you, destroy your brain, & you die. They're both lethal at close range. One is called a lethal weapon & the other something else, but that's one of those "semantic" cavils. Where did this usage come from if not from the royal we? Even the Queen would use an unstressed _us_ after _give_.

Comment: Absolutely, Maggie's usage was the royal we. I'm saying that the royal we is completely different from the usage the OP was asking about. Sorry if my _this_ was unclear.