# Term for/etymology of the opposite of a nosism (using 'we' to mean 'you')

Tags: etymology, phrases, terminology, word-usage

**A [nosism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism) is  the term for using 'we' to refer to oneself.  I am looking for a term for/etymology of using 'we' to mean 'you'.**

---

**EDIT:** Another way of putting it is that I'm looking for the proper term for "the patronising we" (made up) that is mentioned [here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/17966/327571)

---

In the UK, it is somewhat commonplace to hear people (usually of higher authority than the other person) to use 'we' and/or 'our' in place of 'you' and 'your'.

I had a teacher who always used to do this and have ever since wondered why.  For example:

> *Teacher to student:* Why aren't **we** doing **our** homework?
>   
> (Why aren't *you* doing any of *your* homework)
>
> **We** need to start getting that planner signed.
>   (You need to start signing your student planner)

It's sometimes said with a rhetorical question at the end ("__, are we?")

[The Oxford English Dictionary can provide the following:](https://oed.com/view/Entry/226539?rskey=xjbnAO&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> **6.** ***pron.*** Used confidentially or humorously to mean the person or persons addressed, with whose interests the speaker thus identifies himself or herself (esp. by a doctor in friendly or cheering address to a patient); also used mockingly or reproachfully by a parent, intimate friend, etc.

---

I've also realised *we* is often used in the second-person plural for 'you (all)'.  For example, a waiter might ask a group of diners:

> How are **we** doing over here?

Related: [Usage of "we" as plural second-person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/usage-of-we-as-plural-second-person)

**What's the origin of this, what's the proper term for it and please tell me this isn't exclusive to a few people's idiolects.**

Thanks.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xN1WN0YMWZU) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/usage-of-we-as-plural-second-person)?

Comment: The OED dates its first use to 1702, "Well, old Acquaintance, we are going to be Married then?" (John Vanbrugh). It describes the meaning as "Used confidentially or humorously to mean the person or persons addressed, with whose interests the speaker thus identifies himself or herself (esp. by a doctor in friendly or cheering address to a patient); also used mockingly or reproachfully by a parent, intimate friend, etc." No explanation of where it comes from, although you might guess.

Comment: @UriGranta Helpful, but not quite what I'm after.  I'll edit,

Comment: @StuartF Thanks.  If anyone can format this into an answer, with an 'etymology' added, I'd be grateful.

Comment: The first question is certainly a duplicate, with the answer 'patronising _we_' given at the duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm aware of it, I just don't think 'the patronising we' is an actual term; I am pretty convinced the answerer made it up.  I've edited my question.

Comment: Probably related to *Editorial We* and *Author’s We*. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/We

Comment: @user067531 Nice, but those are nosisms (see the top of my question if you don't know what that is).

Comment: yes, but it is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: We" is used sometimes in place of "you" to address a second party: A doctor may ask a patient: "And how are we feeling today?". A waiter may ask a client: "What are we in the mood for?"

***A similar usage exists in other languages.***  in Spanish and Italian, for instance, it is a very common construction

Comment: wegotism (n.) - 
1797, from we + egotism; "an obtrusive and too frequent use of the first person plural by a speaker or writer" [OED].

Comment: @user067531 Ok, that is a good term for an overuse of we, but still not using we to refer to you.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there's no formal term for this? We don't name *everything*.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I will edit my question.

Comment: No, it's not a fixed expression. But the thing to do if a previous duplicate doesn't afford a suitable answer is to offer a bounty, not re-ask.